# How do I get a single value from a json file using angular (without using ng-repeat)?

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a json file with the following data:

```
{
  "favicons": [
    {
      "36x36”: "36x36.png",
      "48x48": "48x48.png",
      "57x57": "57x57.png"
    }
  ],
  "header": [
    {
      "imageUrl": "logo.png",
      "subTitle": “blah”,
      "backgroundColor": "#c30909"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to retrieve the value of `favicons.36x36` without using ng-repeat.

I have this in my app.controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {  
    $http.get("data.json").then(function (response) {
      $scope.faviconData = response.data.favicons;
    })
});
```

Using `{{faviconData}}` in my HTML, I can output the entire array.

But `{{faviconData.36x36}}` results in a parse syntax error.

I have also tried `faviconData[0].36x36` but this also results in an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this

```
{{faviconData[0]['36x36']}}
```